# How to increment row after each step

Tags: python, excel, selenium, openpyxl

Below code is working to increment the row but i don't want to write row+=1 after each step instead, i wanted to write a common function.

```
path = "..//excel//testdata.xlsx"

sheetName = "sheet1"

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

sheet = workbook[sheetName]

row=1

col=1

x=sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value

row+=1

y=sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value

row+=1

z=sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value

row+=1

print("value of x : " ,x)

print("value of y : " ,y)

print("value of z : " ,z)
```

Can someone help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try to use a loop?

Comment: I have not used loops. in my test case i need to write to excel and increment one row after each step.

Comment: Please do a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating the same thing over and over is considered bad practice. Please use a form a looping as explained here for example: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

You will end up with something like:

```
for row in workbook.iter_rows():
  x=sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value
  print("value of x : " ,x)
```